# sublime text ubuntu install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sublimetext3

I am totally new to ubuntu trying to install sublime text. on running command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
```

i am getting this error

```
soumyadeep@soumyadeep-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1254, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1106, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1252, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 849, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 102, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 466, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 484, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1297, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1256, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 327, in get_ppa_info
    ret = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 92, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_lp(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 108, in _get_https_content_py3
    raise PPAException("Error reading %s: %s" % (lp_url, reason), e)
softwareproperties.ppa.PPAException: 'Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/sublime-text-3: [Errno 111] Connection refused'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 393, in shortcut_handler
    return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 356, in __init__
    info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 339, in get_ppa_info
    _get_suggested_ppa_message(user, ppa))
softwareproperties.shortcuts.ShortcutException: Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~webupd8team/ubuntu/sublime-text-3'.
ERROR: '~webupd8team' user or team does not exist.
Error: 'ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3' invalid
```

please help.

Comment: have you considered just downloading the `.deb` file from http://www.sublimetext.com/3 and installing that rather than using a PPA?

Comment: yes i have done but for some reason installation gets started and in a few seconds stops

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the complete output of `sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-3114_amd64.deb` when run in the directory containing the downloaded `.deb` file. This is the preferred way of installing Sublime on Ubuntu, as it automatically gives you update messages when new versions are ready to install.

Comment: @MattDMo I got the same issue while adding repository. I have x86_64 architecture Is the amd64 build okay to go in ubuntu?

Comment: @AdityaGuru yes, x86_64 is the same as amd64.

Comment: @SoumyadeepDasgupta Try sudo apt-get upgrade or sudo apt-get dist-upgrade. Then try sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3

Comment: Then sudo apt-get install -f.

Answer (score 4):

sometime we get trouble while installing sublime on Ubuntu machine.

> Note- Uninstalled Sublime completely if you you have installed previously.

[Here is steps](https://randvblog.wordpress.com/2019/07/11/steps-to-install-sublime-in-ubuntu/) to get installed on fresh **Ubuntu** machine-

step 1: **open terminal**

step 2: `wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`

step 3: `echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list`

step 4: `sudo apt-get update`

step 5: `sudo apt-get install sublime-text`

I installed using these steps, hope will work for you!!!